# Node application not running in test

Tags: node.js, variables, configuration, config, environment

I am trying to configure my node app to run in test mode and use my test environment variables. However, the app keeps running in development mode. Here is my code:

```
exports.config = function(NODE_ENV) {
    if (NODE_ENV = 'development') {
        console.log('in development');
        return env['development'];
    } else if (NODE_ENV = 'test') {
        console.log('in test');
        return env['test'];

    }
}
```

To run my app:

`NODE_ENV=test node app.js`

However, the console log output is:

`in development`

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you passing as argument to that function? Not sure why you're using `NODE_ENV` as a parameter.

```
exports.config = function() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        console.log('in development');
        return env['development'];
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
        console.log('in test');
        return env['test'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually had the wrong = (it needs ===). 

If you `console.log(process.env)` on line 2, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

it is not

```
if(NODE_ENV = 'development')
```

, it is == or safer ===